# Logic gates with Mosfets and Transistors

Tags: mosfet, bjt, logic-gates

Does anyone have a link for the list of all the configurations of BJT and MOSFET which create the logic gates?

Like for NAND gate below:

[image]

Comment: You probably don't want _all_ logic gate configurations, because I am quite sure you can come up with some monumentally bad designs for logic gates.

Comment: What would you suggest?

Comment: The ones actually in use. I was being kind of facetious; I think most people will understand what you want.

Comment: Dont understand, can you explain better please?

Comment: Don't worry about it, evildemonic's answer is a good source for what you want.

Comment: Digital Integrated Circuits by DeMassa and Ciccone

Answer (score 1):

I learned these with a book called "[TTL Cookbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672210355)".  It is pretty dated, and uses BJTs.  You might search for a "[CMOS Cookbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0750699434)" which will use MOSFETS for the same circuits.